# Most efficient way to locate a the presence of a substring in a dictionary (NLP)

Tags: swift, nlp

I'm currently working on a speech recognition feature, where a user can say a command and have that command trigger an event.

The way I have it structured now does work, but mostly because the recognition dictionary is small. It likely will never be millions of commands, but that's no reason to be sloppy.

Here is how it works now:

```
@ObservedObject var speechText
private var matchables: [String:Int] = [["start the action",0], //formal
                                        ["start action",0],     //informal
                                        ["star traction",0],   //common misfire by NLU
                                        ["stop the action",1]]  //different action

//Call processText with lowercase speechText 
//when Observed string value changes

//assume text is conversational, such as "Jenny, I like chicken, also device why
//don't you start the action"
func processText(text: String) {
    for (key, value) in matchables {
        if text.contains(key) {
            executeActionByID(value)
        }
    }
}
```

This will loop through the matchables collection and search for the contents of each key inside of the `text` value. This works fine on a small dictionary, but becomes cumbersome at scale.

I could theoretically break `text` into N-Grams and then access the dictionary directly by key, but this is long running recognition, and `text` might contain a substantial number of words (hundreds?) which may exceed the maximum practical size of the dictionary.

Is there a third, better way to analyze long running streams of text and quickly pick out commands that match a small substring?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my back-of-the envelope thinking about this problem:

Searching for keys in a Dictionary is really fast (almost constant time). Searching strings for substrings using `String.contains(_:)` is slow.  (Around `O(n)` where n is the length of the string.)

As your string length goes up and your number of keys goes up, your time to completion is going to go up by `O(n*x)` (n=string length, x = number of keys.)

That's likely to get slow for longer search strings, and total time will grow geometrically if both your number of keys and string length increase.

I'd suggest breaking your string into discrete units to search for (the obvious way is to divide it with spaces and other separators like punctuation.) If you do that you could check to see if each word appears in your dictionary keys. That should get you roughly `O(n)` time performance, since each search for a key in a dictionary runs in nearly constant time.

Comment: Agreed, and that becomes the issue. What if my string contains 100 words (which is possible, even likely). I split the string into an array, and then combine up to three words (which is my likely maximum phrase length in the dictionary).

Then I'm doing [0], [0]+[1], and [0]+[1]+[2] for every string in my array to compare against the dictionary. That would be 300 operations on the string just to prepare it to search against keys in the dictionary.